# Could not find SQL Server name while connecting

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Cannot find SQL Server name while connecting SQL Server Management Studio:

> (Error-40 Couldn't open the connection to SQL Server)

I tried to find server name in services of Configuration tool, but I found **`'No Items'`** under *Services*.

I tried by using command prompt :

```
SQLCMD -L
```

but it will display:

```
Servers :
```

Comment: That seems to indicate that there is **NO** SQL Server engine installed on your machine - plain and simple. So what **exactly** did you install? If you installed **only** the Management Studio - that's ***ONLY*** the management GUI - but ***NOT*** the database engine (DBMS) - you need to *also* install a database engine - not just the management GUI tools.....

Comment: @marc_s that's what i'm trying to tell her now :)

Comment: Thanks to everyone , I have reinstall SQL server and it is working now

Answer (score 2):

Well I have an easy solution for your question. Follow the steps:

Go to SQL Server Configuration manager
SQL Server Network Configuration:
Protocol for MSSQLSERVER
In the right pane split page you will have to disable VIA as follows
Shared Memory - Enable
Named Pipes - Enable
TCP/IP - Enable
VIA - Disable

do this and tell me whats up :)

Answer (score 2):

Open the sql server configuration manager then click on protocols for SQLEXPRESS2
make sure that named pipes is enabled

[image]

Then you need to create alias for client side
search for cliconfig.exe in system32 (open it)
then create TCP/IP alias

[image]

Then go to alias tab and click add
and write alias for server and write ip address for sql server
and uncheck the dynamically determine port then click ok

[image]

source link: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0gfr2Iyas4)

I hope this help..

windows services SQL Server Instances : [Image Link](https://s27.postimg.org/7iou5wgxf/sql_server.jpg)

Comment: After click on protocols under the Sql server configuration manager,it display 'No items' . Even I have checked SQL Native client .10.0 configuration (32 bit), SQL server Network Configuration ,it displays 'No Items' every-time.

Comment: you need to reinstall the sql server configuration manager

before that open windows services and check if your sql server services status is started

Comment: I have checked 'Services', there is only one 'Sql Sever VSS Writer' service related to SQL and its status is 'Running'.Is this the same Sql Server Service mentioned in the above post ?Please help me out.

Comment: Thanks I have reinstall it and now its working correctly

Comment: @Priyanka I don't know if i deserve the mark for the answer or not..but i'm glad that is worked for you